# Two definitions of representation of a topological group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, topological-groups

Please compare the following two definitions:

**Definition 1**

A representation of a topological group $G$ in a vector space ${\mathbb{V}}$ over complex numbers is a continuous map
$$
  A\, :\quad G\times {\mathbb{V}}\longrightarrow{\mathbb{V}}\;\,,\qquad (g\,,\;v)\longmapsto A(g)\,v\;\,,\;\;\;\;\; g\in G\,,\;\;v\in{\mathbb{V}}\;\; \label{1}\tag{1}
  $$
with the following properties:

(1) $\;\; A\,$ is a group action;

(2) $\;\; A\,$ is linear, i.e.
$$
  A(g)\,(\alpha\, v+\beta)=\alpha\, A(g)\, v+ A(g)\, w\quad \mbox{for}\quad\forall g\in G\,,\;\; v,\; w\in {\mathbb{V}}\,,\;\; \alpha\in{\mathbb{C}}\,\;.
  $$

**Definition 2**

A representation of a topological group $G$ in a vector space ${\mathbb{V}}$ is a homomorphism of $ G$ into the group of invertible linear transformations of ${\mathbb{V}}$:
$$
 A\,:\quad G\longrightarrow GL({\mathbb{V}})\;\,. \label{2}\tag{2}
 $$

$$
\,
$$
**Definition 2 $\;\;\Longrightarrow\;\;$ Definition 1**,

Indeed, the $A$ from **Definition 2** is linear and ensures $\,(g\,,\;v)\longmapsto A(g)\,v\,$.

Also, **Definition 2** says that $A$ is a homomorphism $-$ which guarantees the continuity of $\,(g\,,\;v)\longmapsto A(g)\,v\;$ in **Definition 1**.

QED

To show that **Definition 1 $\;\Longrightarrow\;$ Definition 2**, we must demonstrate that **Definition 1** ensures \eqref{2} being a homomorphism.

How to do this?

Comment: Are you assuming that $\Bbb{V}$ is a vector space over the real numbers, or maybe the complex numbers? (If not then neither of your definitions gives enough information about the topologies involved.)

Comment: @RobArthan Over complex numbers, if that matters. I will now amend my post with this detail. Thank you.

Comment: Definition 2 is not equivalent to Definition 1 unless we put a topology on $\text{GL}(V)$ and insist that the map be continuous. In particular, I disagree with the implication that you wrote.

Comment: @hunter Can we say that homomorphism (2) induces some topology in GL(V) ? Also, if I say that the map in Def 2 is a homomorphism, is it not automatically continuous?

Comment: I think you should try to separate your thoughts about the algebraic content of your problem and its topological content. You don't need any topological reasoning to show that the algebraic part of Definition 1 implies the algebraic part of Definition 2.

Comment: @RobArthan I am puzzled, because both definitions are topological. They are about  representation of a topological group. Am I wrong by suggesting that the group is only topological (and not, say, Lie)? How should I shape the definitions, to be sure that they are equivalent?

Comment: Continuity in Definition 1 is not relevant to the homomorphism property in Definition 2. I am not suggesting that you change the definitions, but that you think about their algebraic content and topological content separately.

Comment: @RobArthan I see that I am confusing homomorphism with homeomorphism!

Comment: The algebraic property of being a group homomorphism has nothing to do with topology. I think you may be mixing up "homomorphism" with "hom**e**omorphism" (an easy mistake to make, in this context).

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, you are right. I am confusing the two. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, a group action by $G$ on a set $X$ is equivalent to a group homomorphism $\psi: G\to \operatorname{Aut}(X)$, where in this case automorphisms are bijections of the set with itself. Indeed, the group action can be thought of as $\alpha:G\times X\to X$ such that $\alpha(hg,x)=\alpha(h,\alpha(g,x))$ etc. This is equivalent to $\psi(hg)=\psi(h)\circ \psi(g)$ where $\psi(g)(x)=\alpha(g,x)$. $\alpha(e_G,x)=x$ for all $x\in X$ is equivalent to $\psi(e_G)=\operatorname{Id}_X$. These are good facts to check carefully yourself as an exercise in the definitions (also usually in any algebra text).

So, definition (1) already gives us a group homomorphism $G\to \operatorname{Aut}^{\operatorname{Sets}}(V)$. A priori, the codomain on the right is self-bijections. However, the requirement that $G$ act linearly means that $G$ maps into $\operatorname{GL}(V)\subsetneq \operatorname{Aut}^{\operatorname{Sets}}(V)$. The continuity of the action stipulated in definition (1) then implies that as a map $G\to \operatorname{GL}(V)$ it is continuous, where $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ is viewed as a topological group.

Comment: I agree that the continuity of action in Definition 1 makes the map $G\longrightarrow GL(V)$ continuous. Does it also make it homomorphism?

Comment: The continuity is unrelated to it being a homomorphism in some sense. As a stupid example, take $\Bbb{C}^\times$ viewed as $G=\operatorname{GL}(1,\Bbb{C})$. Then we can cook up all sorts of continuous maps of groups into $G$. This does not mean the actions are linear. For instance, we could send $S^1$ to $\{z:\lvert z\rvert=2\}$. This does not send the identity of $S^1$ to the identity element of $G$, but it sure is continuous. It is really the algebraic data of being an action that guarantee that we have a homomorphism.

Comment: I see that I am confusing homomorphism with homeomorphism.
Thank you!

Comment: The question here though is whether or not continuity guarantees homomorphism which is very false.

Comment: I now got it. Great thanks!

Comment: Great. I should mention that in my longer comment above that I made a mistake: the map  fails to be a group homomorphism but is valued in linear automorphisms of $\Bbb{C}$.